# Setting the main camera's size to be equivalent to the device's width and height

Tags: unity, 2d

Making a 2D game with Unity. I need a way to set the main camera's width and height to be equal to the mobile device's resolution. So if you're using an iPad Mini 3, then the main camera will be 2048 × 1536 pixels. Or an iPhone 4, it will be 960 × 640.

Is there a way to calculate the main camera's size this way?

---

Here's some data:

For Galaxy S5, which is 1920 x 1080, I found that the camera should have a size of 540, and a viewport rect width of 1.33 and height of 1.

For an iPad mini 3, which is 2048 x 1536, the camera seems to be better with a size of 770. The viewport rect can stay at 1 width and 1 height.

All of that was calculated manually. Surely there is a formula for this?